# Java read a file from jar which is in lib folder of a war

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, jar

I have Spring application in which i am trying to read xml file from jar which is in lib folder of my build application war i.e /WEB-INF/lib/abc.jar.

Right now i am using this code.

```
InputStream reader = SomeClassInabcJars.class
                          .getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/spring/beans.xml");
```

After this i am using DOM parser to get all bean tags from it.

If i deploy this application using command mvn tomcat:run, i am getting proper beans.xml. But if i deploy war of this application manually in tomcat then it seems there are some new bean tags in beans.xml and some bean tags are missing from it.

If i extract this war and open that abc.jar's beans.xml, it seems correct. I think this beans.xml changes at runtime.

Comment: may be it istaking different jar from tomcat's class path which has bean.xml on same path. Most of spring jars have bean.xml in same path. try to set classpath for web-inf libraries first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to read any file from jar which is in lib folder of a build application war file and it worked for me.

```
InputStream reader = null;
for (URL url : ((URLClassLoader) (Thread.currentThread()
        .getContextClassLoader())).getURLs()) {
    if (url.getPath().contains("notification-engine")) {
        String inputFile = "jar:file:" + url.getPath()
                + "!/META-INF/spring/beans.xml";
        URL inputURL = null;
        try {
            inputURL = new URL(inputFile);
            JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection) inputURL
                    .openConnection();
            reader = conn.getInputStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            System.err.println("Malformed input URL: " + inputURL);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.err.println("IO error open connection");
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

It read /META-INF/spring/beans.xml file from path(its a jar path) contain notification-engine.